# Swap list in ul And Active item position remain same

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm new to scripting.
Can someone help me to swap li's in ul 
work Scenarios are :
 1. when user click on anchor tag it should come middle means active position(Active item should always in center position). 
 2. list may not be in order it can be in any order.

```js
var swapElements = function(siblings, subjectIndex, objectIndex) {
  // Get subject jQuery
  var subject = $(siblings.get(subjectIndex));
  // Get object element
  var object = siblings.get(objectIndex);
  // Insert subject after object
  subject.insertAfter(object);
}
$(function() {
  swapElements($('li'), 0, 1);
});
```

```css
ul li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
}

ul li.active a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><a class="nav-item" href="#"><span>Quality</span></a></li>
  <li><a class="nav-item" href="#"><span>Safety</span></a></li>
  <li class="active"><a class="nav-item" href="#"><span>People</span></a></li>
  <li><a class="nav-item" href="#"><span>Cost</span></a></li>
  <li><a class="nav-item" href="#"><span>Delivery</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

I have tried to change the code but no luck.. Can anyone help me to solve my problem.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly consider the following code, with comments given for explanation. Please comment if there is something you do not understand.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  function change() {

   // 1. remove active class from currently active component
   $('.active').removeClass('active');

   // 2. get html inside of the list element
   var htm = $(this).html();

   // 3. remove the list element
   $(this).remove();

   // 4. add a new list element after the 2nd child or (n /2)th child
   $('li:nth-child(2)').after('<li class="active">' + htm + '</li>');

   // 5. bind the change method to clicking of this new element
   $('li:nth-child(3)').click(change);
  }

  // when a list element is clicked, call the change function
  $('li').click(change);

 });
```

```css
    ul li {
      float: left;
      display: inline-block;
      list-style: none;
    }

    ul li a {
      color: #000;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 15px;
      display: block;
    }

    ul li.active a {
      color: red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <ul>
      <li><a class="nav-item" href="#"><span>Quality</span></a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-item" href="#"><span>Safety</span></a></li>
      <li class="active"><a class="nav-item" href="#"><span>People</span></a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-item" href="#"><span>Cost</span></a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-item" href="#"><span>Delivery</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If I do add some other(New) list in it, will it work as expected.?

Comment: @ramyam - Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
If I add some more lists(new li) in the same ul will it work as expected.?

Comment: You will have to adjust the counts 2 & 3 in the list accordingly to 'n / 2' & '(n/2 + 1)'.

Comment: We can't do that dynamically.?

Comment: Of course, you can count the number of children of the '<ul>' element.